# L'étranger (livre) et l'emploi du passé composé

Tags: usage, temps-grammatical, littérature, temps-composés

> J’ai retourné ma chaise et je l’ai placée comme celle du marchand de
>   tabac parce que j’ai trouvé que c’était plus commode. J’ai fumé deux
>   cigarettes, je suis rentré pour prendre un morceau de chocolat et je
>   suis revenu le manger à la fenêtre. Peu après, le ciel s’est assombri
>   et j’ai cru que nous allions avoir un 5 orage d’été. Il s’est
>   découvert peu à peu cependant. Mais le passage des nuées avait laissé
>   sur la rue comme une promesse de pluie qui l’a rendue plus sombre. Je
>   suis resté longtemps à regarder le ciel. A cinq heures, des tramways
>   sont arrivés dans le bruit. Ils ramenaient du stade de banlieue des
>   grappes de spectateurs perchés sur les marchepieds et les rambardes.

http://www.lelibertaire.xyz/Camus_Letranger.pdf

https://genius.com/Albert-camus-letranger-premiere-partie-chapitre-ii-annotated

On attend l'emploi du passé simple dans un contexte littéraire, non ?
Pour quelles raisons (grammaticales? stylistiques ?) Camus emploie le passé composé ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C'est un choix stylistique, car grammaticalement il n'y aurait aucun problème à écrire tout cela au passé simple. Le livre étant écrit comme un récit à la première personne par un personnage de milieu social relativement peu élevé, le passé simple lui aurait peut-être donné un tour trop recherché.

Comment: Merci.   Voulez-vous dire le passé simple ? (le **passé composé** lui aurait peut-être donné un tour trop recherché.)

Comment: @dimitris merci, corrigé !